# Formatting phone numbers for presentation and database entry using flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, phone-number, wtforms

I'm writing a flask app with wtforms backed by a Postgres db.

I want the user to enter phone numbers in pretty much any format, `NNN NNN NNNN`, `NNNNNNNNNN`, `NNN-NNN-NNNN` etc.

I want to store the numbers in the database without any separators `NNNNNNNNNN`

What is the best way to achieve this? I tried putting getters and setters on the form field but this breaks functionality when the field is unbound.

```
class myform(FlaskForm):
    _phone=StringField('Phone #', validators=[Regexp("\d{3}[ ,-]?\d{3}[ ,-]?\d{4}"]

    @propery
    def phone(self)
        return '{}-{}-{}'.format(self._phone[0:3],self._phone[3:6],self._phone[6:10])

   @phone.setter
   def phone(self, value):
        value = value.replace(' ','')
        value = value.replace('-','')
        self._phone = value
```

Answer (score 2):

Although a bit hacky, you can edit the form data in the functions which are being used for validation.

```
def reformat_phone(form, field):
    field.data = field.data.replace('-', '')
    return True

class PhoneForm(FlaskForm):
    phone = StringField('Phone #', validators=[reformat_phone])
    alright = SubmitField('submit')
```

Other options include writing your own phone field class, and rewriting the `process_formdata` function there.

EDIT:

here's the option with making your own field:

```
class PhoneField(StringField):
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        self.data = [v.replace('-', '') for v in valuelist]
        super().process_formdata(self.data)


class PhoneForm(FlaskForm):
    phone = PhoneField('Phone #')
    alright = SubmitField('submit')
```

Comment: +1 for the custom field. Thanks for the demo on how to make that work. I can take care of formatting numbers for presentation in the presentaion laywr which is where it should be.

Comment: @Joost in the case that result is False in `PhoneField` and it desired to return a message, is it posible?